# Segmentation fault при использовании структуры addrinfo в sendto

Tags: c++, сокет, udp

Есть такая обёртка для подключения:

```
int Connect(int &sock, addrinfo *target, string host, string port, bool udp = false){
    if (sock > 0){closesocket(sock);}
    addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = udp?SOCK_DGRAM:SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = udp?IPPROTO_UDP:IPPROTO_TCP;
    if (getaddrinfo(host.c_str(),port.c_str(),&hints,&target) != 0){return -1;}
    if ((sock = socket(target->ai_family, target->ai_socktype, target->ai_protocol)) == -1){return -1;}
    return connect(sock, target->ai_addr, target->ai_addrlen); // free addrinfo after use
}
```

Почему при такой конструкции приложение завершается с ошибкой на `sendto` (даже try/catch не работает):

```
addrinfo *target;
int udp_sock;
int error = Connect(udp_sock, target, VoIP_Data.host, VoIP_Data.port, true);
// далее идёт краш...
int result = sendto(udp_sock, frame.c_str(), frame.size(), 0, target->ai_addr, target->ai_addrlen);
```

А при такой отправка работает (правда потом крашится на `freeaddrinfo`, но это не важно):

```
addrinfo target; // без указателя
int udp_sock;
// передаём адрес target
int error = Connect(udp_sock, &target, VoIP_Data.host, VoIP_Data.port, true);
int result = sendto(udp_sock, frame.c_str(), frame.size(), 0, target.ai_addr, target.ai_addrlen);
```

Хотелось бы использовать функцию-обёртку для подключения с возможностью использовать далее `addrinfo` как в первом случае, но не понятны причины краша.

*PS: всё работает корректно если алгоритм функции подключения написать прямо в `main` без отдельной функции.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логично, что оно падает. Внутри функции Connect Вы берете адрес &target - но это адрес переменной на стеке. После выхода с функции она теряется, а оригинальная переменная target продолжает показывать туда, куда и раньше - в неизвестные дали (потому что нужно переменную инициализировать, в данном случае nullptr, тогда проблема быстро бы всплыла).

Так как target показывает неведомо куда, то другие функции, которые ее используют, ведут себя непредсказуемо.

Как исправить.

Объявляем так

```
addrinfo *target = nullptr;
```

сигнатуру функции Connect пишем так

```
int Connect(int &sock, addrinfo **target, string host, string port, bool udp = false)
```

вызываем так

```
int error = Connect(udp_sock, &target, VoIP_Data.host, VoIP_Data.port, true);
```

и в остальных местах поправить соответстующее. (подсказка `(*target)->ai_addr`).

Comment: А как быть в последних двух строках функции, при вызове `socket` и `connect`? С разыменовываием не компилит...

Comment: просто здездочка не помогает?

Comment: Не-а. request for member 'ai_family' in '* target', which is of pointer type 'addrinfo*'

Comment: там, если я правильно помню, нужно так `(*target)->ai_addr`

Comment: ДА! Спасибо огромное!